# Conversion of itab into XML puts an extra character at begin of file

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, transformation, abap

I am using the following code to save data in an internal table as an xml file.
But an extra '#' character gets appended to the file.
If i remove this extra '#' the browser is able to read the xml.

```
REPORT ZGAURAV1.
types: begin of struct,
   col1 type i,
   col2(5),
  end of struct.

  data: it type STANDARD TABLE OF struct.
  data: wa type struct.
  wa-COL1 = 1.
  wa-COL2 = 'abc'.
  APPEND wa to it.
  wa-COL1 = 2.
  wa-COL2 = 'def'.
  APPEND wa to it.

    data: xml_out TYPE string.

call TRANSFORMATION id
source output = it[]
RESULT XML xml_out.

data: xmltab type STANDARD TABLE OF string.
append xml_out to xmltab
.
CALL FUNCTION 'DOWNLOAD'
EXPORTING
  filename = 'C:\USERS\GAURAV\DESKTOP\TESTING.XML'
  filetype = 'ASC'
TABLES
  data_tab = xmltab
```

The XML file that gets created is

```
#<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0"><asx:values><OUTPUT><item><COL1>1</COL1><COL2>abc</COL2></item><item><COL1>2</COL1><COL2>def</COL2></item></OUTPUT></asx:values></asx:abap>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried using replacement parameter in GUI_DOWNLOAD as suggested by @Suncatcher. But now there is an extra space in the beginning of the file because of which the browser is unable to read the xml.How does a space in the beginning makes the browser unable to read the xml?I created another xml and added spaces but the browser was able to read it.
The created xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0"><asx:values><OUTPUT><item><COL1>1</COL1><COL2>abc</COL2></item><item><COL1>2</COL1><COL2>def</COL2></item></OUTPUT></asx:values></asx:abap>
```

If i remove the extra space,it works fine.

Comment: What I can suggest is to change the browser, as previous speakers said:) Extra-space shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a replaced BOM (byte-order mark). Replacing the obsolete function module `DOWNLOAD`is a good idea (although I'd recommend replacing it with `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_DOWNLOAD`), but removing the replacement character is not always a good idea since it will drop ANY unknown character throughout the entire string. If the browser is unable to read a BOM, then it's the browser that is broken in the first place. If you still need to remove the BOM, do so in the ABAP coding using `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>BYTE_ORDER_MARK_*`.

Comment: @user3311810 Yes, but you haven't implemented the suggested solution (removing the BOM on the ABAP side).

Comment: Can you please mention the syntax to remove the BOM in abap.

Comment: That is basic data handling in ABAP. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GUI_DOWNLOAD` instead of the obsolete `DOWNLOAD`.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_DOWNLOAD'
EXPORTING
   filename    = 'C:\USERS\GAURAV\DESKTOP\TESTING.XML'
   replacement = ''                                    "pay attention to this parameter
TABLES
  data_tab     = xmltab.
```

Parameter REPLACEMENT should be set to space during the call of this module. Default behavior of the FM (with omitted parameter) puts `#` when the input character cannot be converted to the result codepage.